Need help clicking Microsoft Teams button using Selenium Python
I'm using Python with Selenium and I'm automating the login on Microsoft Teams. Once I get in, this pop-up shows that I need to click "Switch Now" to switch to the V2 version. I can't seem to successfully click this button using Selenium Python. Can anyone help me click this button automatically?
Here was my unsuccessful attempt:
self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ts-sym ts-btn ts-btn-fluent ts-btn-fluent-primary app-switcher-install-by-policy-dialog--btn").click()

